# what is the precedence for chef/knife bootstrap json attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

The documentation for Chef attribute precedence is here: https://docs.getchef.com/chef_overview_attributes.html

However, the docs don't really explain what level is applied to attributes that are passed in via the -j flag for the knife bootstrap command.

The reason why I'm asking is because I'm passing in attributes and some of those attributes aren't being applied correctly to my run.

Comment: Can you post your knife command?  The format of the json you pass in is important to getting correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Stuff passed in via -j are set as the node data, which are the `normal`/`set` level.

Comment: Same as normal, just an alias. The level is generally called `normal` but the API used to access it is `node.set`.

Comment: What would you suggest as a proper debugging procedure to find out why an attribute isn't being picked up from that json flag and applied to the run? I've checked the attributes down the chain and everything is set as default.

Comment: In your recipe file:

require 'pp'; pp node.debug_value('some', 'attribute', 'path')

Comment: Okay, so my problem never had to do with the wrong attributes being passed in but rather how Chef handles attributes during the compilation phase.


How do you do this: node["attribute"] = node["other_attribute"]?


I've tried using lambdas and lazy attribute loading but when I pass in a normal attribute node["other_attribute"] is set but node["attribute"] is not - it's locked at what I set in the attributes file.

Answer (score 0):

As @coderanger pointed out, they should be at the `set` level if you are formatting your json correctly.  If your Json isn't formatted correctly, it won't set the values at all, but may not give you an error.

For troubleshooting, you can use `node.debug_value` to see the whole attribute tree.

Or if you want a shortcut, use the [spicerack cookbook's](https://github.com/tejaycar/spicerack) print_attribute_debug recipe to grab it and print it.  The cookbook as a whole is still really immature, but the README gives the usage details and it's plenty good for debugging purposes.

Comment: It has nothing to do with formatting, it is impossible to set things at a level other than normal via -j (or any other method of setting node data).

Comment: Sorry, I clearly didn't make that very clear.  My point was that if the Jason isn't formatted right the attributes aren't set at all.  But if it's well formatted Jason it will not throw an error either.